# procedimientos almacenados mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, insert

Tengo  el siguiente   error en mysql  en un  insert

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> 1366 - Incorrect integer value: '_codigo_Postal' for column 'codigoPostal' at row 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertar_dir(
_est VARCHAR(100),
_municipio VARCHAR(100),
_colonia VARCHAR(100),
_calle VARCHAR(100),   
_codigo_Postal INT,
_num_e INT, 
_num_i INT, 
)  

INSERT INTO direcciones(estado, municipio, colonia, calle, codigoPostal, num_Exterior,  num_Interior)VALUES('_est', '_municipio', '_colonia', '_calle', '_codigo_Postal', 'num_e', 'num_i');
SET @clave_dir = (SELECT   clave_dir FROM direcciones WHERE clave_dir=(select MAX(clave_dir) from direcciones))
```

OJO  si lo  pongo sin comillas  no me  reconoce  el campo

Comment: Los valores que estas colocando estan mal ya que tu columna es INT y estas pasandole valores varchar.

Comment: las variables las estas ingresando con comillas, deben estar sin ellas por que si no, te las reconoce como texto, en el caso de que no te reconozca las variables verifica si esta activa la conexión o si el proceso que llama a el procedimiento estas enviado bien los parámetros.

Comment: Bienvenido @Luis Jorge Muñiz Villarreal a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTA:** Sé que la pregunta es de Procedimientos pero para realizar los queries respectivos tuve que crear la tabla, además había cuestiones de sintaxis que debían trabajarse primero.

Hay varias cosas a tener en cuenta cuando creas la tabla en **MySQL** por ejemplo verificar que la tabla exista y que tenga una clave primaria... aunque esto último lo agrego para la función `MAX` que voy a emplear después.

Si se observa `_num_i` es la clave primaria y por tanto necesita que este vaya aumentando su valor conforme se adicionen datos a la tabla `direcciones`. Para eso se emplea `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS direcciones(
    _est VARCHAR(100),
    _municipio VARCHAR(100),
    _colonia VARCHAR(100),
    _calle VARCHAR(100),   
    _codigo_Postal INT,
    _num_e INT, 
    _num_i INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (_num_i)
);
```

Con la tabla creada -muy importante el nombre debe coincidir `direcciones`- se adicionan los datos teniendo en cuenta la naturaleza o tipo de valores que puede ser ingresado en cada columna, como ya han señalado algunos usuarios en sus comentarios.

```
INSERT INTO direcciones --# el nombre coincide con la tabla creada previamente
            (_est, _municipio, _colonia, _calle, _codigo_Postal, _num_e)             
       VALUES("EstadoUNO","MunicipioDiez", "ColoniaCentral","CallePrincipal", 500, 20);

INSERT INTO direcciones --# el nombre coincide con la tabla creada previamente
            (_est, _municipio, _colonia, _calle, _codigo_Postal, _num_e)            
       VALUES("EstadoDOS","MunicipioCinco", "ColoniaSUR","CalleConexa", 700, 35);
```

Una vez con los datos ingresados se puede ver la estructura de la tabla direcciones con `SELECT * FROM direcciones;`

Ahora podemos hacer un `primerQuery` que de acuerdo al post, intuyo necesitas,  por ejemplo saber cuál es el mayor `_num_i` asociado al `"MunicipioDiez"`

```
SELECT * FROM direcciones 
WHERE _municipio = "MunicipioDiez" AND
       _num_i= (SELECT MAX(_num_i)
                FROM direcciones
                WHERE _municipio = "MunicipioDiez");
```

Lo otro que se aprecia del post, es la definición de variables usando `SET @...` por tanto se efectúa el mismo `primerQuery` pero teniendo presente este detalle del `SET`:

```
SET @miMuni := 'MunicipioDiez';

SELECT @indiceMax := _num_i AS '_num_i' --# @indiceMax toma un valor el AS '_num_i' se puede omitir
FROM direcciones 
WHERE _municipio = @miMuni AND
    _num_i= (SELECT MAX(_num_i)
             FROM direcciones
             WHERE _municipio = @miMuni);
```

Si deseamos saber cual es el valor de la variable `@indiceMax`

```
--# Comprobamos que la variable se grabó con este query
SELECT _num_i
FROM direcciones
WHERE _num_i = @indiceMax;

--# o también se puede visualizar la variable
SELECT  @indiceMax;
```

Esta última expresión es la más práctica para obtener el valor de una variable definida con `SET` en **MySQL**, incluso se puede aplicar para `SELECT @miMuni;` y se obtendrá `MunicipioDiez`.

Comment: Gracias   Excelente   respuesta,  lo   que  sucede   es  que  ese  procedimiento  lleva   varios   INSERT consecutivos por  eso  utilizo  los  SET  para  recoger   y   guardar    las  "llaves",  y posteriormente  pasarlos  a  otro  INSERT. Al  final  lo resolví  modificando 3  cosas    1.- Cambie  el identificador "_" por  (N en caso de  ser  tipo INT y V en caso de  ser  VARCHAR).  2.- quitar  las comillas  simples    a  los   VALUES(a  todos).  3.-quite   los  parametros  " sql  STRICT_MODE"  del  archivo  my.ini.   gracias  por  tomarte  el tiempo de  responder